# How do I go about making the change password route in my restAPI?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, bcryptjs

I am currently doing this to register users:

```
const register = async (req, res) => {
  const seller = await Seller.create({ ...req.body });
  res.status(StatusCodes.CREATED).json({ seller });
};
```

I am using the pre-save function to hash the passwords:

```
 SellerSchema.pre('save', async function () {
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});
```

But when making the password change function which I have made like this:

```
 const updatePassword = async (req, res) => {
      const { id } = req.params;
    
      const { oldPassword, newPassword } = req.body;
    
      const seller = await Seller.findOne({ _id: id });

      if(!seller) throw new NotFoundError(`No seller with id:${id} exists`)
    
      const isPasswordCorrect = await seller.comparePassword(oldPassword);
      if (!isPasswordCorrect) {
        throw new UnauthenticatedError('Invalid Credentials');
      }
      seller.update({ password: newPassword });
    
      await seller.save();
    
      res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ seller });
    };
```

But what happens is the pre-save function hashes the existing password before saving; how do I make it hash the incoming password? I know I can remove the pre-save function and just use it in the controller. But is there any way to do this by using the pre-save function?

Comment: i am not still clear on what is your issue. but as i assume you are getting error of Invalid Credentials for valid old password. If that is the case can you tell me what exactly you are doing in your  comparePassword method?

Answer (score 0):

```
  const updatePassword = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  const { oldPassword, newPassword } = req.body;

  const seller = await Seller.findOne({ _id: id });

  if(!seller) throw new NotFoundError(`No seller with id:${id} exists`)

  const isPasswordCorrect = await seller.comparePassword(oldPassword);
  if (!isPasswordCorrect) {
    throw new UnauthenticatedError('Invalid Credentials');
  }
  // Correct this line of code 
  seller.password=newPassword

  await seller.save();

  res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ seller });
};
```

Comment: Please explain your answer with more details, how it solves the question and how it works.